# Can I attach clothes with ropes & solid objects in blender for simulation?

Tags: blender, cloth-simulation

I'm trying to create a boat sail & simulate the sail moving by the wind force

but I can't make the the clothes attached to other objects and move them by the wind force like this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-DQdzhTH6PA

Comment: You might want to post this question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: Thanks, i will post it there.